How do I encode molecular data in a way that a QCBM can read?
I am doing research on drug discovery with quantum computing. I am using a Quantum Circuit Born Machine and and LSTM for my generative step. I used an algorithm to take experimentally verified ligands and expand them to a large library of ligands that are similar (~1000). From what I understand I need to convert these ligands (Written as SELFIES strings) into a probability distribution so that the QCBM can learn this. How do I do this in python? Also is Quantum Embedding of information the same as the probability distribution needed for the QCBM to read? I am including a paper that has a similar methodology but does not detail how they did this.
Here is the arXiv link to the paper.
